# What is the name of the feature where one includes a set of options at the bottom of a file to be invoked immediately when opening it?

Tags: modeline

Basically something like this:

```
.
.
bla
.
.

<special incantation of vim>
set tabstop=2
expandtab
set foldmethod=marker
<end-of-file>
```

I know that Emacs has the same feature, which is how I found it the last time, but no joy this time around...

(Chose the `formatting` tag because I had to choose one.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name you're looking for is `modeline`. See the doc for the syntax [`:h modeline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#modeline) and [`:h 'modeline'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27modeline%27)

Comment: Yes! The feeling when the empty void, that has been gnawing at the back of the head, finally implodes. Thanks!